# looking for a faster way to help reduce/create a huge list of strings

Tags: c++, data-structures, runtime

I tried to write an algorithm to guess correctly in the game "Masterminds",
it works the average number of guesses is 6, but it takes a lot of time to calculate the best guess.

I used the idea of Knuth the algorithm works as follows:

> 1. Create the set S of 1296 possible codes (1111, 1112 ... 6665, 6666).
> 2. Start with initial guess 1122 (Knuth gives examples showing that other first guesses such as 1123, 1234 do not win in five tries on
>      every code).
> 3. Play the guess to get a response of colored and white pegs.
> 4. If the response is four colored pegs, the game is won, the algorithm     terminates.
> 5. Otherwise, remove from S any code that would not give the same response if the current guess were the code.

In my code step 2 is to take random number.

I used `vector<string>` for this.

`AllPoss` is the vector full of strings, I guess is the last guess that was used. `answer` is the count of bulls and cows looks like "x,y" (where x and y are numbers)

```
void bullpgia::SmartGuesser::remove(string guess, string answer)
{
    for (auto i= AllPoss.begin();i != AllPoss.end();i++){
        string token = *i;
        if (calculateBullAndPgia(token, guess) != answer)
        AllPoss.erase(i--);
    }
}
```

this is the part it take a lot of time to calculate is there any way of improvement?

to creating the list i used :

```
void bullpgia::SmartGuesser::All() {
    /**
     * creates a pool of all the possibilities strings
     * we then delete the ones we dont need
     * @param length is the length of the word we need to guess
     */
    for(int i=0;i<pow(10,length);i++){
        stringstream ss;
        ss << setw(length) << setfill('0') << i;
        string s = ss.str();
        AllPoss.push_back(s);
    }
}
```

the function calculateBullAndPgia(string , string) is:

```
string calculateBullAndPgia(const string &choice, const string &guess) {
    string temp = choice;
    string temp2 = guess;
    unsigned int bull = 0;
    unsigned int pgia = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
        if (temp[i] == temp2[i]) {
            bull++;
            temp[i] = 'a';
            temp2[i] = 'z';
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < temp2.length(); j++) {
            if (i != j && temp[i] == temp2[j]) {
                pgia++;
                temp[i] = 'a';
                temp2[j] = 'z';
            }
        }
    }
    return to_string(bull) + "," + to_string(pgia);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erasing a single element in the middle of a vector is O(n). My guess is that you wind up doing it O(n) times per call to `SmartGuesser::remove`. Then you loop over that so you probably have a O(n^3) algorithm. You instead could use `std::remove_if`, which is O(n), to move all the to-be-erased elements to the end of the vector where they can be cheaply erased.:

```
AllPoss.erase(std::remove_if(AllPos.begin(), AllPos.end(), [&](const std::string& token, const std::string& guess) { return calculateBullAndPgia(token, guess) != answer; }), AllPos.end());
```

Comment: Good point.  Not related, but for the same reason, in `bullpgia::SmartGuesser::All()`  there should be a `AllPoss.reserve(pow(10,length));` in order to avoid that the array is moved several time due to its growth.

Comment: Sure, but that’s not a big-O improvement since `push_back` is amortized O(1).

Comment: i tried to implement this part in my code but the linker went mad for it (pic) https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501831081680
thank you for the help!

Comment: @Ben what if i use a list will that improve my O(n^3) or some other data structure?

Comment: I can’t see that link. My suggestions shouldn’t affect linking because they are all header-only libraries. As for `std::list`, that should work too although my approach will be faster (but the same big O).